# Sum over permuted and unpermuted indices

Tags: summation, permutation, products

I would like to write a code to evaluate the following (up to $N=20$)

$\sum_{s_1,...,s_N=\pm 1;s_1 \cdot \cdot \cdot s_N=1}\sum_{\sigma\in S_N}\prod_{i=1}^N x_{\sigma(i)}^{s_i \lambda_i}$

There are several discussions on here which tell me how to perform such a computation provided all the i's were permuted. However I do not know how to deal with this case.

Comment: Why? What will you learn? For N = 20, the number of different permutations is larger than 2*10^18. Multiply that by 2^19 to get all the sums over the `s[i]` and you got yourself a waiting game.

Comment: By itself this doesn't teach me anything. It is part of a slightly more complicated function involving another variable t. I am aware of the combinatoric nightmare here and maybe N=20 is too much to ask, but if I can even look at the expansion to first order in t for example it will be useful as the x's are expected to form characters of some representation of a Lie group, which tell me about the symmetry of the problem I am looking at. What about N=6? Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
bigSum[lambdalist_List] :=
 Block[{n, slist, sn, sigmalist, xlist},
  n = Length[lambdalist];

  slist = Tuples[{-1, 1}, n - 1];
  sn = Times @@@ slist;
  slist = Transpose[Append[Transpose[slist], sn]];

  sigmalist = Permutations[Range[n]];

  Sum[
   xlist = x /@ sigma;
   Sum[
    (Times @@ (xlist^(s*lambdalist)))
    , {s, slist}
    ]
   , {sigma, sigmalist}
   ]
  ]
```

It takes 0.25 s to run `bigSum[Range[6]]`, which is when $N=6$, $\lambda_i = i$.

Comment: This does it! Thank you :)